# model pulling apart when skinning

Tags: rigging

I am working on skinning a character using automatic weights, and weight paint. As I work, I am finding it difficult to keep seams together, and stitching stuck to the model while keeping things smooth. Does anyone have some techniques or words of wisdom to help with this?

Default pose

[image]

Posed

[image]

Comment: for the moment the sleeve is a separated mesh, the easiest would be to make only one mesh and parent again

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure though why that happened. But  you can join the sleeve and stitches with ctrl+J in object mode if they are sperate object. Or select every thing,  go to edit mode and search for (merge by distace) option (F3). And apply it.  It will join the vertices which almost share the same place.
Remember  after doing this you have re assign the weight.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I probably did not describe it super well. They are joined into the same geometry container (using ctrl+j), but not connected or "linked" together into a continuous piece of geometry. I have a lot of geometry in this model that is similar.